# Can you find out which compiler was used to compile a program?

Tags: compiler-construction, identification

Given an executable that is compiled from C to run on Solaris, is it possible to determine which compiler was used to compile the associated incomplete executable?

I can't see anything when using either the strings or the file command, and magic doesn't seem to contain anything specific.

Do compilers generally put a fingerprint in their executable output files?

cheers,

Comment: Nice question. I assume there are differences (even between versions and compiler settings) but detection of the compiler won't be a trivial task.

Comment: Interesting question. What OS are you thinking of?

Comment: It also depends on how much you have to work with.  For instance gcc creates different o files than cc.  If you have a static program or a dynamically loadable program you can also see which libraries is used.  IN other words, your fingerprint is in logic not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the executable isn't stripped, try /usr/ccs/bin mcs-p
This will usually show the compiler, linker and all the header files used

Answer (score 6):

Yes IDA is great for this. It uses a technology called [FLIRT](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/flirt.htm).

Answer (score 4):

[PEID](http://www.peid.info/) will do the trick. It generally works just great. Obviously PEID is a windows tool but it shouldn't matter and should show you to compiler (sometimes even specific version information)

Comment: Works for PE files only. Solaris is ELF or possibly a.out

Answer (score 2):

Build small test apps with each compiler you're trying to identify. Then look at the results in a hex editor, and try to find patterns.  It might turn out to be really obvious -- for example the ["Rich" signatures](http://www.ntcore.com/Files/richsign.htm) from Microsoft's linker.

Answer (score 1):

Not stripped:

$ cc -O hello.c

$ file a.out

a.out:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, dynamically linked, not stripped

$ strings -a a.out | grep cc

/opt/solarisstudio12.3/prod/bin/cc -O  hello.c

$ dwarfdump -i a.out | grep compile_o

DW_AT_SUN_compile_options   Xa;O;R=**Sun C 5.12 SunOS_sparc Patch 148917-07** 2013/10/18;backend;raw;cd;

Stripped:

$ strip a.out

$ file a.out

a.out:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, dynamically linked, stripped

$ strings -a a.out | grep cc

(none)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio and GCC typically follow different startup routines (which call main). That maybe a hint. I don't know about others though. For dlls, can't think of something similar off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers usually add their own personal "signature" as plaintext in the compiled files. You can use a tool such as strings to suss the plaintext out.