# How can I determine which framework was used to build a particular Windows desktop application?

Tags: frameworks, reverse-engineering

How can I determine which platform or programming language was used to build a particular Windows desktop application?

Comment: You mean other than asking them?

Comment: Without any information what you mean by software it's hard to give you a good answer. Are you speaking about web-based apps, desktop software, windows, *nix, Mac, ...?

Comment: WINDOWS SOFTWARE ..
EXAMPLE NOKIA PC SUITE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to try and detect in which language a particular software was written. Usually, the tools that do that examine the [PE Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) and try to make an educated guess.

Sometimes authors compress/encrypt the PE in such way that makes this detection next to impossible.

There is an old tool called [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/) which can help you identify in which language was the software written.

[image: PEiD]

Answer (score 5):

The [Dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com) may also shed some light by showing all the dlls the application depends on, as well as the names of the exported methods.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are some options for specific situations, but in general, no, there is no one single and reliable way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

[ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from SysInternals can be useful. It can detect .NET applications, and it lists loaded DLLs, which can help if some of them are runtime support for a language or framework.

I happen to have Nokia PC Suite installed, and ProcessExplorer says it is not a .NET application. It has loaded MFC71U.DLL and MSVCR71.DLL, which [I believe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984696(VS.71).aspx) are from [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) - of course Nokia PC Suite could simply be using a component written in MFC. Also there are some strings inside the EXE which look like C printf strings to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to narrow down the list to what language is used, but you cannot know all the 'hows'.  Plus what if there are a number of developers on different platforms? ;)

Or better yet the app is a combination of languages?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if techniques developed for natural [language identification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification) and [authorship identification](http://tinyurl.com/authorship-identification) can be adapted to this problem. It seems to me an interesting enough research problem.

A somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618491/can-you-find-out-which-compiler-was-used-to-compile-a-program) has already been posed.